# Why does reducing an Array of Option with ap result in None?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I am trying to do this for learning. But I can't get it to work (big surprise since you're reading this :) )

The algo:

- Have a mixed list of valid/invalid objects as input
- Extract the desired property from each object (or null)
- Transform to a list of Options
- Reduce the list of Options by using a function that operates on Aggregate types.

I couldn't get the types to work by elegantly lifting `sumAggregates` so I tried to do it with `pipe, ap`. But I would like to see how we would properly lift `sumAggregates` to be used in the reduce.

Please note that my goal isn't to get the correct result in a different way, but to learn why my implementation of this one fails.

```js
  type Actionable = {
    action?: string
  }
  type Aggregate = {
    allowed: number,
    blocked: number
  }

  const emptyAggregate: Aggregate = {
    allowed: 0,
    blocked: 0
  }

  const list: Actionable[] = [ { action: 'block'}, { }, { action: 'block'}, { }, { action: 'allow'}]

  const extractAction = (a: Actionable) => a.action
  const stringToAggregator = (str: string): Aggregate => {
    return {
      allowed: str === 'allow' ? 1 : 0,
      blocked: str === 'block' ? 1 : 0,
    }
  }
  const sumAggregates = (a: Aggregate) => (b: Aggregate): Aggregate => {
    return {
      allowed: a.allowed + b.allowed,
      blocked: b.blocked + b.blocked,
    }
  }

  const totals: O.Option<Aggregate> = pipe(
    list,
    A.map(extractAction),
    A.map(O.fromNullable),
    A.map(O.map(stringToAggregator)),
    A.reduce(
      O.some(emptyAggregate),
      (a: O.Option<Aggregate>, b: O.Option<Aggregate>) => {
        return pipe(O.of(sumAggregates), O.ap(a), O.ap(b))
      }
    )
  )
```

Returns `None` instead of `some({allowed: 1, blocked: 2})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You end up with `None` because one of the elements in the list in the `reduce` is a `None`, and you pass that `None` to `O.ap` in the reducer.

Take a look at the definition of `ap` for `Option` [here](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/2d70be4785fec90aed119d2ec075faef36116321/src/Option.ts#L323). The lifted computation does not get called when provided a `None` and the result of the `ap` becomes `None` as a result. So what would you expect the result to be for the following most basic computation?

```js
import * as O from 'fp-ts/Option'
import {identity, pipe} from 'fp-ts/function'

const result: O.Option<number> = pipe(
  O.some(identity),
  O.ap(O.none),
)
```

It would be `None` right? That is the effect that `Option`'s apply/applicative instance is known for. So in your `reduce` function, once a `None` is encountered and passed to `ap`, the accumulator ends up in the `None` case, and no further applications of `sumAggregates` can be performed.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to replace the line `return pipe(O.of(sumAggregates), O.ap(a), O.ap(b))` with something else that works correctly (so, keeping the approach effectively the same, except for that function of the reducer), or is it impossible and a different algorithm must be used instead?

Comment: @rollingBalls I believe something like this would work: `return pipe(O.of(sumAggregates), O.ap(a), O.ap(pipe(b, O.alt(() => O.some(emptyAggregate)))))`

Comment: Thank you! The usage `alt` is illuminating to me.
There's probably some minor tweak needed somewhere else because it now returns `{ _tag: 'Some', value: { allowed: 1, blocked: 0 } }` (while the value before the reducer is `[{"_tag": "Some", "value": {"allowed": 0, "blocked": 1}}, {"_tag": "None"}, {"_tag": "Some", "value": {"allowed": 0, "blocked": 1}}, {"_tag": "None"}, {"_tag": "Some", "value": {"allowed": 1, "blocked": 0}}]`).

But that doesn't matter, I understand now. Thanks again!!